# Custom encoding map multiple characters to one byte

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I am trying to write a custom encoding, which allows me to use a table file to map specific characters to bytes. Unfortunately there are characters which are not inside the common unicode sheet (Like buttons of a video game, end of string identifiers, special ligaturs) which I wanted to include into my encoding via escapes, for example "\du" or "direction up" would map to an arrow kind of character. Problem is, if the encoder gets a character buffer "mid-sentence" there might not be the complete escape string in the buffer, and my program throws an exception. (This happens when using streams for example, they create 1-4kb chunks of char data)

Is there a way of telling the C# Encoder to "reconsider" the string, like abort here but when slidng further take a look at the characters again because they might eventually be incomplete?

My code, if of any help looks as follows:

```
public override int GetBytes(char[] chars, int charIndex, int charCount, byte[] bytes, int byteIndex)
    {
        if (chars == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("chars");
        if (charIndex > chars.Length || charIndex < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charIndex");
        if (charIndex + charCount > chars.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("charCount");
        if (bytes == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("bytes");
        if (byteIndex > bytes.Length) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("byteIndex");

        string s = new string(chars, charIndex, charCount);
        int pos = 0;
        int num = 0;
        while (pos < s.Length)
        {
            int len;
            bytes[byteIndex + num] = Table.Encode(s, pos, out len);
            pos += len;` 
        }
        return num;
    }
```

Table.Encode:

```
public byte Encode(string s, int position, out int length)
{
    s = Regex.Replace(s, "\r\n|\r|\n", _lineBreak);
    if (position > s.Length || position < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("position");
    //Characters is an array with conversion information, like "A -> 07h" or "\du -> 1fh"
    for (int b = 0; b < Characters.Length; b++)
    {
        if (Characters[b].Matches(s, position))
        {
            length = Characters[b].Length;
            return (byte)b;
        }
    }
    //Is thrown if there is an unmatched character
    throw new Exception("Unmatched Character.");
}
```

Comment: Read on UTF-8 encoding - it allows to detect start of "character" by clever use of high bits.

Comment: It is not me who invented the format I am trying to implement, so no clever use there...
Anyhow I don't know how that would help me, I know that every single character is just one byte, the problem occurs when encoding the text into bytes, not decoding it. (Which works fine, since even a stream can't pass "half" bytes :D)

Comment: The other built-in encodings have the same problem. UTF-8 cannot be split on arbitrary boundaries. You need to implement an `Encoder`. Encoders work incrementally.

Comment: I completely misunderstood the question as "how to implement custom encoding/decoding" instead of "implement `System.Text.Encoder`"... Indeed as @usr pointed out `Encoder` stores state (specified on [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoder(v=vs.110).aspx) too : A Encoder object maintains state information between successive calls to GetBytes or Convert methods so that it can correctly encode character sequences that span blocks. )

Comment: @usr Am I right that if I want to use streams with my encoding I need to use an Encoding class? How does the framework know that it should use an Encoder (Which the encoding also provides) instead of the methods built in encoding?

Comment: Encoding can return an Encoder. Decompile StreamReader.

Comment: @usr Do you think decompiling would be preferable to reading actual code like [Encoder](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/text/encoder.cs,c9dcc13a2975ad7b) ?

Comment: Whatever you like. I find Reflector to be clearer than real code. You can see all members at once and lots of noise is removed. I often learn new APIs by Reflector.